# what are the advantages and disadvantages of assigned password?

Tags: encryption, passwords, privacy, attacks

I am trying to understand if it is good or bad if an application assigns an initial password to each user and, at an appropriate time, assigns a new password. The user has no role in choice of passwords or frequency of change. what are the pros and cons of it.